# how to use conditional require file in files backend

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

i need to use a conditional require inside a file.

this is my db.config file in cloud
`var dbConn = require('../config/db.config')`;

but in local i need to use other config.
i think if is possible to do

`var dbConn = process.env.ISLOCAL || require('../config/db.config')`;

where ISLOCAL = require('../local/config/db.config')

Comment: Do you mean `var dbConn = process.env.ISLOCAL ? require('../local/config/db.config') : require('../config/db.config')`?

Comment: or just use process.env.ISLOCAL if we are in local because we have de .env in the folder, or use the other file.....?

Comment: If your configuration data is JSON (would be natural since you're developing in JavaScript), use **[wj-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wj-config)**.  It will do your configuration for you based on the value of the current environment.